# Playwright: How can I use a token generated by an API to be used across all tests?

Tags: automated-tests, token, playwright

I have an authentication API endpoint  that generates an `accessToken`. I would this token to be temporarily saved and then used / executed across all my other API tests every run with the setup / test snippet below:

```js
const url = 'https://serverless.net/api/authority/token';

    await request.post(url, {
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        // Add authorization token to all requests.
        'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${process.env.USERNAME}:${process.env.PASSWORD}`).toString('base64')}`, }
    });
/// this generates an `accessToken` in the body
```

The API response body would have something like:

```json
{
    "result": 0,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
        "accessToken": "eyasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsa",
        "tokenType": "Bearer",
        "expiresIn": "1440",
        "userId": 1
    }
}
```

where I would need the `accessToken`.

Can I write / save this to a temporary storage (maybe a json file?) then use it as a `Bearer token` for my API tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using Playwright's `global-setup` (https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown).

First, on the root directory, I created `global-setup.ts` with the following code. The gist is to save the `accessToken` from the response body into an environment variable `process.env.TOKEN`:

```js
import { FullConfig, request } from '@playwright/test';

async function globalSetup(config: FullConfig) {
    const baseURL = config.projects[0].use.baseURL;
    const url = '/api/authority/token';

    const requestContext = await request.newContext();
    const response = await requestContext.post(`${baseURL}${url}`, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${process.env.USERNAME}:${process.env.USER_ADMIN_PASSWORD}`).toString('base64')}`
            }
        });

    const body = await response.json();
    process.env.TOKEN = body.data.accessToken;
}

export default globalSetup;
```

I then included the following lines in my `playwright.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.ENVIRONMENT}` });

export default defineConfig({
  globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup'),
  ...
```

Lastly, on my tests, I just simply call the `process.env.TOKEN` with something like below:

```js
test('api that calls the auth token', async ({ request }) => {
  const url = '/my-api-endpoint';

  const response = await request.get(`${baseURL}${url}`, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.TOKEN}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
  });
```

Comment: This is not good way to pass header info in individual tests as in case when needs to be changed, you may end up modifying many tests.

Comment: Kindly explain how it will end up modifying many tests as changing anything on the `global-setup` will be done once and will not need to modify all tests. Even if your logic is true then how different is your original solution (exactly copied from the Playwright site) different from that logic? I have explained nicely that `storageState` won't work as your API / UI needs to generate cookies. I was helped by Playwright team with the above solution and the reason I posted it is to help others with similar situation.

Comment: @ebanster I tired the solution you propose, My question is that, global-setup is the funtion name or this is the name of the class too? which you are including in cofig file

Comment: @Sara I actually responded to your question but got deleted my mods.

Comment: @ebanster - Thank you . This post and answer was a huge help .I was struggling using  storagestate , and was not getting anywhere

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes , you can store it globally and pass in tests in multiple ways.

Follow this example from [Playwright Docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing#configuration):

In this example GitHub API requires authorization, so it will configure the token once for all tests. Also we can set the baseURL to simplify the tests. You can either put them in the configuration file, or in the test file with test.use().

**To get auth detail from API and store it in local json file**:

```
// auth.setup.ts
import { test as setup } from '@playwright/test';

const authFile = 'playwright/.auth/user.json';

setup('authenticate', async ({ request }) => {
  // Send authentication request. Replace with your own.
  await request.post('https://github.com/login', {
    form: {
      'user': 'user',
      'password': 'password'
    }
  });
  await request.storageState({ path: authFile });
});
```

You may also specify storageState for each test file or test group, instead of setting it in the config.

```
// tests/example.spec.ts
import { test } from '@playwright/test';

test.use({ storageState: 'playwright/.auth/admin.json' });

test('admin test', async ({ page }) => {
  // page is authenticated as admin
});

test.describe(() => {
  test.use({ storageState: 'playwright/.auth/user.json' });

  test('user test', async ({ page }) => {
    // page is authenticated as a user
  });
});
```

#### In case you have auth token, and want to pass globally in Configuration

```
   // playwright.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';
export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    // All requests we send go to this API endpoint.
    baseURL: 'https://api.github.com',
    extraHTTPHeaders: {
      // We set this header per GitHub guidelines.
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
      // Add authorization token to all requests.
      // Assuming personal access token available in the environment.
      'Authorization': `token ${process.env.API_TOKEN}`,
    },
  }
});
```

#### Writing Tests:

Playwright Test comes with the built-in request fixture that respects configuration options like baseURL or extraHTTPHeaders we specified and is ready to send some requests.

```
const REPO = 'test-repo-1';
const USER = 'github-username';

test('should create a bug report', async ({ request }) => {
  const newIssue = await request.post(`/repos/${USER}/${REPO}/issues`, {
    data: {
      title: '[Bug] report 1',
      body: 'Bug description',
    }
  });
  expect(newIssue.ok()).toBeTruthy();

  const issues = await request.get(`/repos/${USER}/${REPO}/issues`);
  expect(issues.ok()).toBeTruthy();
  expect(await issues.json()).toContainEqual(expect.objectContaining({
    title: '[Bug] report 1',
    body: 'Bug description'
  }));
});
```

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing#configuration

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I would need to generate the token first as part of my setup (it's like I need to run this first like a `before` hook before executing the tests) and in your example, it seems that we assume there is already a token generated with `process.env.API_TOKEN`

Comment: @ebanster  Updated the answer in detail , hope that helps.

Comment: The `auth.setup.ts` is what I tried previously and didn't work (hence, I went Stackoverflow :D ). It gives me an error: `Error: apiRequest.newContext: storageState.cookies: expected array, got undefined`. Someone told me that using the setup above is based on assumption that the API sets a cookie. I updated my original ask with the sample response body which doesn't seem to save on the user.json file.

Comment: Ok ,so where and in which form your token is being saved currently if you do it manually or by some other tool like postman?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question correctly but it is a typical REST API that generates a response body with data `accessToken`. I can run it on the Playwright tests using `request.post` or manually in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

if you add the header in the playwright config file like below we wouldn't need to be copy it around in every test.
.
.
.
use: {
...
baseURL: "https://api.example.com",
extraHTTPHeaders: {
Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
},
...
},

.
.
.